# Pull twitter profile picture without Auth / API with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Is there a way to pull someone's profile picture from Twitter and display it on my site without Auth or Twitter API?

I think it was possible with API v1.1 but support for that has been stopped.

Any suggestions or advice?

Comment: Since there doesn't appear to be any real meaningful link between the user's screen name and the URL of their profile link, you won't be able do this without OAuth

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question to remove that suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

There's the easy way, or the hard way :-)

The easy way is to use a service like http://avatars.io/

Simply call `http://avatars.io/twitter/edent` to get my avatar.

**The hard way?**

You can scrape it directly off the Twitter site.  It's not pretty - but it works.

If you look at the source for my Twitter page - https://twitter.com/edent - you will see this block of HTML.

```
<a href="/settings/profile"
   class="account-summary account-summary-small"
   data-nav="edit_profile">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="account-group js-mini-current-user" data-user-id="14054507" data-screen-name="edent">
      <img class="avatar size32" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/417381475101593601/UUi48hOg_normal.jpeg" alt="" data-user-id="14054507">
      <b class="fullname">Terence Eden</b>
      <span class="screen-name hidden" dir="ltr">@edent</span>
      <small class="metadata">
          Edit profile

      </small>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

You can look for the first instance of `<img class="avatar size32"` and grab the `src` from that.

Comment: I really appreciate the suggestion! So would I use an ajax call for this? I'm not entirely sure how to scrape data from a webpage...

Comment: Just use the easy way :-) If you know their username, just go for http://avatars.io/twitter/Whatever

Comment: Can't really use a service for this I'm afraid. Cheers though. Just need to figure out how to scrape html now...